# laravel - Can I add new items to an array that already has some existing items?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, variables, laravel-8

`var_export($response)` is an array like below:

```
array (
   0 =>
    array (
    'courseId' => 14,
    'tutorName' => 'admin',
    ),
   1 =>
    array (
    'courseId' => 15,
    'tutorName' => 'merl',
    ),
 )
```

The below code gives a result like this: `"data": 3`. I wanted add a new item called `points` with the `$response` array, into all elements. But here, it overwrites the existing array. How can I achieve this?

```
$dat=array_push($response,array('points'=>"3"));
return response()->json(['data' => $dat], 200);
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "courseId": 14,
        "tutorName": "admin",
        "points": 3
    },
    {
        "courseId": 15,
        "tutorName": "merl",
        "points": 3
    }
]
```

Comment: Note: [`array_push()`](https://php.net/array_push) returns the new number of elements in the array.

Comment: oh.ok.thanks. Can u also tell me how can i achieve my expected output?

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us a dump of `$response` value (eg: `var_export($response)`) please, instead of JSON?

Comment: @Syscall see the updated question body. I've added `var_export($response)`

Comment: Thank you. So, you want to add `"points" => 3` to the first element only, and return it ?

Comment: @Syscall .yes. i need to get added as an item the array

Comment: @PHPHuppTechnologies can't do that. becoz, doing that will add the item points to the first array only. i want this item `points` to get added to all sets of data in this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, [`array_push()`](https://php.net/array_push) returns the new number of elements in the array. That's why you get `3`.

You can add your value in all elements of the current response, like this:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    $response[$key]['points'] = 3;
}
```

Then, just return the response :

```
return response()->json($response, 200);
```

Comment: but doing this will add the item `points` to the first array only. i want this item `points` to get added  to all sets of data in this array

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: or `$response = array_map(function($e) { $e['points'] = 3; return $e; }, $response);`, instead of foreach.